# How to replace empty string with NA in R dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr, na

My first approach was to use `na.strings=""` when I read the data in from a csv. This doesn't work for some reason. I also tried:

```
df[df==''] <- NA
```

Which gave me an error: Can't use matrix or array for column indexing.

I tried just the column:

```
df$col[df$col==''] <- NA
```

This converts every value in the entire dataframe to NA, even though there are values besides empty strings.

Then I tried to use `mutate_all`:

```
replace.empty <- function(a) {
    a[a==""] <- NA
}

#dplyr pipe
df %>% mutate_all(funs(replace.empty))
```

This also converts every value in the entire dataframe to NA.

I suspect something is weird about my "empty" strings since the first method had no effect but I can't figure out what.

EDIT (at request of MKR)
Output of `dput(head(df))`:

```
structure(c("function (x, df1, df2, ncp, log = FALSE) ", "{",
"    if (missing(ncp)) ", "        .Call(C_df, x, df1, df2, log)",
"    else .Call(C_dnf, x, df1, df2, ncp, log)", "}"), .Dim = c(6L,
1L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), ""), class = 
"noquote")
```

Comment: Ryan is right. I'm curious, why are you creating a function for it though? Is it just to get it in a dplyr pipeline?

Comment: Huh I was under the impression it was setting the value in the function and a return wasn't necessary. But even with the return, it changes everything to NA. And yes I would prefer to fit in a dplyr pipeline but even outside the function it was not working.EDIT: I'm slow with my comments but let me update the question with some other things I tried.

Comment: @Ryan Okay your ifelse worked somehow. Not sure why over all the other things I tried but I'll take it. Thanks!

Comment: If you have decided to use `dplyr` then you can use `mutate_all(df, funs(na_if(.,"")))`

Comment: I'm not sure why `df[df==''] <- NA` didn't work for OP.

Comment: please post `str(df)`

Comment: @mp3242 You can just post output of `dput(head(df))`.

Comment: @MKR see edit to my question, and also my comment to your answer.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I'm not sure why `df[df==""]<-NA` would not have worked for OP. Let's take a sample data.frame and investigate options.

**Option#1:** Base-R

```
df[df==""]<-NA

df
#    One  Two Three Four
# 1    A    A  <NA>  AAA
# 2 <NA>    B    BA <NA>
# 3    C <NA>    CC  CCC
```

**Option#2:** `dplyr::mutate_all` and `na_if`. Or `mutate_if` if the data frame has multiple types of columns

```
library(dplyr)

mutate_all(df, list(~na_if(.,"")))
```

OR

```
#if data frame other types of character Then
df %>% mutate_if(is.character, list(~na_if(.,""))) 

#    One  Two Three Four
# 1    A    A  <NA>  AAA
# 2 <NA>    B    BA <NA>
# 3    C <NA>    CC  CCC
```

**Toy Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(One=c("A","","C"), 
                 Two=c("A","B",""), 
                 Three=c("","BA","CC"), 
                 Four=c("AAA","","CCC"), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df
#   One Two Three Four
# 1   A   A        AAA
# 2       B    BA     
# 3   C        CC  CCC
```

Comment: The first one fails for a `tbl` with the error that OP had, though the `df$col[df$col == ''] <- NA` version seems to work fine.

Comment: Welp I think it was because I was using tibbles. Small detail but important I guess. When I change temporarily to data frames with data.frame() and use option one above, then it works.

Comment: @mp3242 You can even use option#2 which is compatible to even `tibbles`.

Comment: @MKR Thanks! Option two is even better than Ryan's solution `mutate_all(~ifelse(. == "", NA, .))` since Ryan's somehow completely mangled any column with type S3: integer64. I wonder why yours works fine? EDIT: this is even without using mutate_if()

Comment: @mp3242 I have `na_if` call. Moreover as I have mentioned in my answer that if there are other types of columns than you can use `mutate_if`.

Comment: @MKR  The correct test for objects of type character is:    is.character,  NOT is_character.

Comment: Two follow-ons a year and a half later:  #1 `funs(na_if(.,""))` is now deprecated and should probably be `list( ~ na_if(., ""))` and #2 @MKR `is_character` is an available function in `purrr` and aims to be more consistent than `is.character`.

Comment: @ChuckP Thanks. I have updated answer based on your comments.

Comment: @MKR @ChuckP How to do that in `dplyr` way using `across()` instead of `mutate_if()` (since it is depreciated)?

Comment: @Art: `df %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ na_if(.x, "")))` should work

Comment: or `One:Four` instead of `where(is.numeric)` for MKRs Toy Data

Comment: Would someone mind explaining the meaning of the tilde `~` in this context?

Answer (score 15):

Here's using the latest syntax (Feb, 2022). This version only sets "" values to NA for character columns. Very handy, as the simpler version will throw an error if you're using anything besides character columns.

```
# For character columns only, replace any blank strings with NA values
df <- df %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.character), ~ na_if(.,"")))
```